# reducing running time for matlab for loops

Tags: matlab

my matlab code bellow takes a very long time to run. How could I compose it to take just seconds to run? I would be thankful if you could help me. parameters i, k_hat and alpha are constants.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

p_desired=zeros(1,length(alpha));
p_ICI=zeros(1,length(alpha));
p_MUI=zeros(1,length(alpha));
tic
for ss=1:length(alpha)
    uN=2*pi/N*Ts*abs(sin(alpha(ss)));
    uM=2*pi/M*Ts*abs(sin(alpha(ss)));
    for j=0:M/N-1
        for k=0:N-1
            for q=0:N-1
                for qq=0:N-1
                    for q_hat=0:N-1
                        for qq_hat=0:N-1
                            for n=0:M-1
                                for m=-Ng:M-1
                                    for n_hat=0:N-1
                                        for m_hat=-Ng:N-1
                                            if (n-m-n_hat+m_hat==0)
                                                if (i==j && k==k_hat)
                                                    p_desired(ss)=p_desired(ss)+((sin(-alpha(ss))-1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(1i/2*q^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*q*k_hat/N)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))+1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(-1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(-1i/2*q_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*q_hat*k_hat/N)...
                                                        * ((sin(alpha(ss))-1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(1i/2*qq^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*qq*k_hat/N)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))+1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(-1i/2*qq_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(-1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*qq_hat*k_hat/N)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))-1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(1i/2*(q+N*(i-1))^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(1i/2*n^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*(q+N*(i-1))*n/M)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))+1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(-1i/2*(q_hat+N*(i-1))^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(-1i/2*n_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*(q_hat+N*(i-1))*n_hat/M)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))-1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(1i/2*m^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(1i/2*(qq+N*(i-1))^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*m*(qq+N*(i-1))/M)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))+1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(-1i/2*m_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(-1i/2*(qq_hat+N*(i-1))^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*m_hat*(qq_hat+N*(i-1))/M)...
                                                        *exp(1i*2*pi/M*(n-n_hat)*e)*exp(-abs(n-m)/gamma)* besselj(0,2*pi*abs(n-n_hat)*fd);
                                                elseif (i==j && k~=k_hat)
                                                    p_ICI(ss)=p_ICI(ss)+((sin(-alpha(ss))-1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(1i/2*q^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*q*k_hat/N)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))+1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(-1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(-1i/2*q_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*q_hat*k_hat/N)...
                                                        * ((sin(alpha(ss))-1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(1i/2*qq^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(1i/2*k^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*qq*k/N)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))+1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(-1i/2*qq_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(-1i/2*k^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*qq_hat*k/N)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))-1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(1i/2*(q+N*(i-1))^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(1i/2*n^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*(q+N*(i-1))*n/M)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))+1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(-1i/2*(q_hat+N*(i-1))^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(-1i/2*n_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*(q_hat+N*(i-1))*n_hat/M)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))-1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(1i/2*m^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(1i/2*(qq+N*(i-1))^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*m*(qq+N*(i-1))/M)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))+1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(-1i/2*m_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(-1i/2*(qq_hat+N*(i-1))^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*m_hat*(qq_hat+N*(i-1))/M)...
                                                        *exp(1i*2*pi/M*(n-n_hat)*e)*exp(-abs(n-m)/gamma) *besselj(0,2*pi*abs(n-n_hat)*fd);
                                                elseif (i~=j)
                                                    p_MUI(ss)=p_MUI(ss)+((sin(-alpha(ss))-1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(1i/2*q^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*q*k_hat/N)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))+1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(-1i/2*k_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(-1i/2*q_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*q_hat*k_hat/N)...
                                                        * ((sin(alpha(ss))-1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(1i/2*qq^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(1i/2*k^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*qq*k/N)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))+1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/N)^.5*exp(-1i/2*qq_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uN^2)*exp(-1i/2*k^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*qq_hat*k/N)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))-1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(1i/2*(q+N*(i-1))^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(1i/2*n^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*(q+N*(i-1))*n/M)...
                                                        *((sin(alpha(ss))+1i*cos(alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(-1i/2*(q_hat+N*(i-1))^2*cot(alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(-1i/2*n_hat^2*cot(alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*(q_hat+N*(i-1))*n_hat/M)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))-1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(1i/2*m^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(1i/2*(qq+N*(j-1))^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(-1i*2*pi*m*(qq+N*(j-1))/M)...
                                                        *((sin(-alpha(ss))+1i*cos(-alpha(ss)))/M)^.5*exp(-1i/2*m_hat^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*uM^2)*exp(-1i/2*(qq_hat+N*(j-1))^2*cot(-alpha(ss))*Ts^2)*exp(+1i*2*pi*m_hat*(qq_hat+N*(j-1))/M)...
                                                        *exp(1i*2*pi/M*(n-n_hat)*e)*exp(-abs(n-m)/gamma)* besselj(0,2*pi*abs(n-n_hat)*fd);
                                                end
                                            else
                                                p_desired(ss)=p_desired(ss);
                                                p_ICI(ss)=p_ICI(ss);
                                                p_MUI(ss)=p_MUI(ss);
                                            end
                                        end
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: Looks like you wrote a code that wrote this code xD

Comment: Did you get this from a paper or something? While I *could* sit down and work out what your code is doing, I don't have the time. If you can present it in a more easily digestible form I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove "`for ss=1:length(alpha)`" and corresponding "`end`"
2. Convert all "`alpha(ss)`" to "`alpha`"
3. Convert all "`p_desired(ss)`" to "`p_desired`"
4. Convert all "`p_ICI(ss)`" to "`p_ICI`"
5. Convert all "`p_MUI(ss)`" to "`p_MUI`"
6. Convert all "`*`", "`/`" and "`^`" to "`.*`", '`./`' and "`.^`" respectively.
7. Convert "`elseif (i~=j)`" to "`else`"
8. Remove below code:

> else
>
> ```
>     p_desired(ss)=p_desired(ss);
>
>     p_ICI(ss)=p_ICI(ss);
>
>     p_MUI(ss)=p_MUI(ss);
> ```